# How to use GMP with NS3?

Tags: c++, makefile, gmp, ns-3

When calling `__gmpz_set_str()` in a NS3, I got this error:

undefined reference to `__gmpz_set_str` collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am already including `#include <gmpxx.h>` and I have also installed `libgmp3-dev` and `libgmp-dev`.

Any idea?
this is the link to the waf: https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/waf
and the link to the wscript: https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/wscript

```
# This is the make file content:

#Makefile wrapper for waf

all:
    ./waf

#free free to change this part to suit your requirements

configure:
    ./waf configure --enable-examples --enable-tests

build:
    ./waf build

install:
    ./waf install

clean:
    ./waf clean

distclean:
    ./waf distclean
```

Comment: Are you *linking* with gmp? Show your Makefile and linker invocation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Can we see the waf build script then? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68437605/edit) instead of smushing it into the comments.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show how you "call __gmpz_set_str() in a NS3" so we can try to reproduce your issue? Clearly my answer is trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile flags need to be set at configure time, so the correct incantation is:

```sh
LDFLAGS=-lgmp ./waf configure
```

Now, you can simply run `./waf` to build the entire codebase, and the `-lgmp` flag will be used. If you *really* want to use make(1), then

```sh
LDFLAGS=-lgmp make configure
```

should also work, but I recommend just using waf directly since it is the actual build system, not make.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to the top of your Makefile:

```
export LINKFLAGS = -lgmp
```

This will interact with [some lines in the wscript](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/wscript#L700-L707) to make sure the linker includes libgmp.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.