# Use OpenCv inside NS3

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, ns-3

I'm working with ns3 and I have built my own module and I need to use OpenCv inside it. So I edited the wscript to look like this:

```
def build(bld):
 bld.env.append_value("LIB", ["opencv_core", "opencv_ml"])
 //other stuff..
```

Then in the main module.cpp I import opencv like this:

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/ml.hpp>
```

and later in the code I try to build a knn and train it:

```
void module::TrainKnn()
{
 cv::Ptr<cv::ml::KNearest> knn = cv::ml::Knearest::create();
 cv::Mat train_data;
 //other stuff
}
```

Now the problem arise when I try to compile with ./waf:

> "undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::Mat()'"

This means that somehow the link for `cv::Mat` which is inside OpenCv_Core did not work, but it works for `cv::ml::KNearest` which is inside Opencv_ml.

If I try to compile a simple program outside ns3 with the same function TrainKnn I need to run `g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld -L/home/davide/opencv-4.5.4/build/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml` and the program compile and works fine.
So I tried to edit the wscript by adding:

```
def configure(conf):
 conf.env.append_value("LINKFLAGS", ["-L/home/davide/opencv-4.5.4/build/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml"])
 conf.env.append_value("LIB", ["opencv_core", "opencv_ml"]
```

But the problem persist. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried passing loader flags to waf like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68489503/13040392)? Directly modifying the waf scripts is a bit fragile.

Comment: Do I have to write something like: `LDFLAGS=-L/home/davide/opencv-4.5.4/build/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml` ? Do I need to keep the wscript modified? Do you have perhaps a link on how to use .waf parameters?

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include the *exact* error message you obtain when building with `./waf`?